# Javascript logical operator || reads 0 as a false value. Is there a NICE way around this?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

Sorry, I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to javascript. But here is my problem:
The following function returns -1 when 0 is inputed

```
function foo(bar){
    return bar || -1;
}

foo(0);
```

is there a nice and elegant way to allow the || operator to read 0 (specifically 0, not all falsy values) as a valid value so that the function retuns 0? Or do I have to do this:

```
function foo(bar){
    if(bar === 0){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return bar || -1;
    }

}

foo(0);
```

Edit:

Thank you everyone for your answers!
For those wondering, the question was asked to find the solution to the same issue with optional parameters. The following code is an example of how it could be applied.

```
function Point(x,y,meta){    //meta is an optional parameter. In this case I wanted to set meta to 0, but it was being set to null.
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    //this.meta = meta || null; This line is the old code that would set meta to null when 0 is inputed.
    this.meta = meta === 0 ? 0 : (meta || null);    //the fix suggested by many users is applied here.
};

var foo = new Point(1,2,0);
console.log(foo.meta); //foo.meta is now 0 instead of null!
```

Comment: In what cases do you want to get `-1`, exactly? The falsy values are `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `+0`, `-0`, `NaN`, `""`.

Comment: For the record, I have no idea why this would be downvoted. Truthy and falsy values are a complicated subject in JS. Additionally, the OP created a very concise example of their problem to demonstrate their question.

Comment: `foo(Infinity)` what output do you expect here ?

Comment: @SumnerEvans I did not downvote, but, this problem is so specific it gives off a strong "X Y" vibe. Al tough an isolate example is always a good idea, It could be helpful if OP would state hit actual intent as well, so he can get help with is actual problem instead of his attempted solution.

Comment: @Oriol Sorry for the confusion, I didn't know concepts of +0 or -0 existed (I'm relatively new to programming). I will change the question to note that I was specifically looking for cases with the value 0 (not all falsy values) so that other people can use the question as a reference.

Comment: @LotsoSheeps `+0` and `-0` are almost the same (`0 === -0`), but `1/0 === Infinity` and `1/-0 === -Infinity`.

Comment: @Oriol Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The tightest you can get is to collapse your if-else in to a single return, a la:

```
return bar === 0 ? bar : (bar || -1);
```

Because || compares truthy/falsy values, you have to explicitly handle (using strong typing) the `0` case.

It's hard to tell from your question, but usually when I'm overriding the truthy/falsy nature of comparisons, it's to default a value. In that case, it's to detect if my function has been given an undefined value, and to use some sane default in its place.

Comment: This returns true if `bar === 0`.

Comment: This is certainly the most "elegant" solution posted.

Comment: I tried this but the function now returns true when 0 is inputed.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite foo like this using the ternary operator:

```
function foo(bar) {
    return bar === 0 ? 0 : (bar || -1)
}
```

The syntax for the ternary operator is `condition ? expr1 : expr2`. If `condition` is truthy, it will return `expr1`, otherwise it will return `expr2`.

[Here's more information on the ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: I like the explanation of ternary! Maybe it would be beneficial to change "true" to "truthy" to make it a bit clearer that `true ? a : b` and `1 ? a : b` both result in `a`?

Answer (score 1):

That's the way JavaScript works. All values are either truthy or falsy. Zero happens to be a falsy value. You can simplify your function with a ternary though.

```
function foo(bar) {
    return bar === 0 ? 0 : (bar || -1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo(bar){
    return typeof bar === "undefined" || bar === null ? -1 : bar;
}

foo(0); // should give 0
foo(false); // should give false
var a; //  undefined variable 
foo(a); // should give -1
foo(null); // should give -1
var b = {}; // object
foo(b.a); // should give -1 (undefined property)
```

Well, the intention of this `if` is to check for missing (non-present) value. In JavaScript the value is missing if it is:

1. `undefined`
2. `null`

The best way to check something for `undefined` is to strictly (===) check its **type** for equality to "undefined" string - this way you don't get an exception if `bar` can't be evaluated.

But, if your expression is not `undefined`, you can then safely check its' value with comparison `bar===null`.

Thus, we have both cases covered and we are not getting exceptions.

Comment: I think this is the best code, but an explanation of why would be helpful.

Comment: Well, the intention of this `if` is to check for missing (non-present) value. In JavaScript the value is missing if it is:
1) `undefined` 
2) `null`.

The best way to check something for `undefined` is to strictly (===) check its **type** for equality to "undefined" string - this way you don't get an exception if `bar` can't be evaluated. 
But, if your expression is not `undefined`, you can then safely check its' value with comparison `bar===null'.
Thus, we have both cases covered and we are not getting exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The other approach is to look at the number of arguments received and set `default` value that way.

```
function foo(bar){
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
      return -1;
    }
    return bar;
}
```